# checkpoint is not a docker command

Tags: docker

I want to use checkpoint in docker. I refer this doc to learn.[enter link description here](https://circleci.com/blog/checkpoint-and-restore-docker-container-with-criu/)
But I have some problems. When I type docker checkpoint $cid, docker tell me checkpoint is not a docker command, I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
Wangs-MacBook-Pro:~ wxc575843$ export cid=$(docker run -d busybox tail -f /dev/null)
Wangs-MacBook-Pro:~ wxc575843$ docker checkpoint $cid
docker: 'checkpoint' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
```

Comment: Did you install the dependency as described in the [docs](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md)?

Comment: What version of docker do you use? what does it show when you do `docker --help`?

Comment: My docker version is 1.12.0. docker --help command list the command I can use in docker. But it is not include docker checkpoint.

Comment: I see the doc of criu, but I am not sure if criu can install on OSX.

Comment: I install criu as the doc say. But the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Docker supports "checkpoint and restore" of a container, thanks to the CRIU integration with Docker. But, it is in the **experimental mode** so be careful.

The **correct command** to checkpoint a Docker container :

```
docker checkpoint create [OPTIONS] CONTAINER CHECKPOINT
```

Reference :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint_create/

**An example** of how to checkpoint and restore a container in a single host is given:

[Container migration in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288677/container-migration-in-docker/47595390#47595390)

Answer (score 0):

The client and daemon API must both be at least 1.25 to use this command.
Or Docker Version 1.13 and above. 
Also, you need to enable experimental mode in your docker engine.

check this out:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30996